# What is a good manner to see if a sequence of functions is uniform converging, when you're in the last stage of checking

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

What is a good manner to see if a sequence of functions is uniform converging, when you're in the last stage of checking, i.e. finding an N that satisfies  $|f_n(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon$?

Example: $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ on the domain $[-1,1]$

Last stage: $$|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}|$$
I'd think that the next step is 
 $$|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}|<|\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}|$$
(Because 1 is the biggest value possible for $x$ and the second step being:
$$|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}|<|\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}| < |\frac{n}{1}|$$  (making the denominator as small as possible).  I understand that $\frac{n}{1}$ will go to infinity and that is bigger than $\epsilon$, but I don't know in what kind of function sequences, it isn't possible to find an $x$ that satisfies all sequences. I only see that it doesn't converge uniform (and find it logical that it doesn't) after the teacher tells me.

I hope that my question is clear despite the broken English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you started out trying to prove an *upper* bound. If this worked out logically, then it would show uniform convergence. It didn't: you got an upper bound that doesn't go to zero.

So now the question is: does the sequence actually still converge uniformly, and your estimates were too sloppy, or should you use this as a hint that maybe the sequence doesn't actually converge uniformly? One great thing about using *tight* bounds, or at least nearly tight bounds, is that it automatically answers that question for us. In other words, if you had shown that $|f_n(x)| \leq n$ and in the process identified $x_n$ so that $|f_n(x_n)|=n$ (or $|f_n(x_n)| \geq n/2$ or something similar) then you would have just learned that the sequence doesn't converge uniformly, without having to start a whole separate calculation seeking out a lower bound. Sure, you'd still need to do that calculation to finish a rigorous proof, but you'd already know the answer. Figuring out the answer is often harder than proving that it is the answer.

The problem with your work, then, is that your bounds aren't tight at all. Your first bound is plenty tight: the numerator is $n$ at $x=\pm 1$. But the $x$'s where that bound is useful are all near the boundary. You then turn around and try to make the denominator small, but doing that requires you to go *away* from the boundary, which makes your previous estimate unhelpful.

So you need a different approach. Here's a hint: $f_n(x)=g(nx)$ where $g(y)=\frac{y}{1+y^2}$. So except at $x=0$, waiting for $f_n(x)$ to go to zero is equivalent to waiting for $nx$ to blow up. Does the size for $n$ required for that depend on $x$?

Comment: So every time I need to check if the n is dependent on the x for converging pointwise to its limit function? 
My second question is in what kind of situations(function sequences) is looking at the boundaries of the domain useful to find a  tight bound. Or aren't there specific  kinds of function sequences?

Comment: @HasanAks It's really situational. In general it can be useful to find the absolute extrema of $f_n-f$, if that is possible, because those are where you will see $\| f_n - f \|_\infty$. Or you might find extrema of a simpler function and then show that the simpler function is close to $f_n-f$. In this particular case you actually could find the extrema (the derivative is a rational function with a quadratic numerator, whose roots can be found).

Comment: first of all, I really want to thank you for all your help.  Second of all, I did find the derivative and the extrema was + or - 1/n       How to show that it is close to f$_n$(x)-f(x)  now?   ( I also tried to fill it in:  f$_n$(1/n) and the result was 1/2 )   So could you help me with the next step?

Comment: You found the extrema are at $\pm 1/n$, now $f_n(\pm 1/n)=\pm 1/2$ which doesn't go to zero, so $\| f_n - f \|_\infty$ doesn't go to zero.

Comment: So is this a good algorithm to check for uniform convergence  
1)check the pointwise convergence  limit  (If it is continues, go to step 2)
2) sup (for all x in Domain)  | $f_n$(x) - f(x)|     (= let say  z)
3) if  z  goes to 0,  you have uniform convergence,  if it doesn't go to zero there isn't uniform convergence  ?  

And you can find the value for step 2  by taking the derivative and setting it equal to 0

Comment: @HasanAks In principle, yes. In practice, exactly finding the extrema is usually not possible, so you need to do some context-dependent approximation in step 2.

Comment: You really helped me thanks again!   So every case is separate and there isn't a way for finding the value in step2  that will work in at least 50% of the cases?

Comment: @HasanAks In "school problems" you will probably be able to find the extrema more often than not. In more realistic problems finding the extrema explicitly will not be possible. You can often figure it out by just thinking about the graph: for instance in my answer I pointed out $f_n(x)=g(nx)$, now does the graph of $g$ have extrema? It must: it vanishes at $0$ and at $+\infty$ and is not identically zero, so there must be an extremum in between, say $x_0$. Then $f_n(x_0/n)=g(x_0)$ couldn't possibly go to zero.

Comment: Everything I had question marks about is clear to me now.